# Does OneDrive delete files after joining a family?

Tags: onedrive

I joined an Office 365 (now Microsoft 365) family about a month ago, and I now have 1 TB of storage. Prior the joining the family, I had some files with the free account. Now, I cannot find those files. Is there any way to recover them?